# How to merge Plaid Items after duplicate created

Tags: plaid

I'm working on an app that uses Plaid for receiving transactions from banks and storing them for later use and analyzing. And I'm having an issue handling when duplicate Items have been created. I wanted to know if anyone has found a way to deal with duplicates.

The Plaid site says [this](https://plaid.com/docs/link/duplicate-items/#preventing-duplicate-items):

[image]

But I can't confirm whether the `institution_id` is guaranteed to be remain consistent between duplicates.

**P.s.** If anyone has figured out how to efficiently match the transactions between the Items too, feel free to share

Answer (score 0):

The `institution_id` identifies the institution where the account is located. By definition duplicate accounts will be associated with the same institution, so they have to have the same `institution_id`.

A general answer to dealing with duplicate Items (preventing them if possible; if not possible, deleting the old Item and replacing it with the new Item) is described in the article you linked. Beyond that, how deal with duplicate Items on a business logic level will depend on your application's business logic.